# NSString comparing

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, cpu-word

I am searching for an algorithm where I can compare two strings and read out the failers.

I know the normal code to compare two strings but this isn't enough.

Example:

```
NSString *userinput = @"xaplseiPhonr";// (Input from the user)
NSString *correct =@"apple iphone";
```

In the next step i would check this strings and put out the failers for this example:  x,l,s, ,r = 5 failers

I tested many things, saved the two strings in an array with two for-loops and compared it but something is wrong, the hardest thing is if the word has 2 letters that are the same. Or if you have no dynamic index search then are the whole letters after the "l" or the missing space in the userinput false, and so on.

So, It would be nice if anyone has fine code for me

---

edit: code to compare, but this doesn't work if you missed a letter or space.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [originalWordLetters count]; i++) 
{
    NSString *originalLetter = [originalWordLetters objectAtIndex:i];

    //NSLog(@"%i: %@", d, originalLetter);
    BOOL letterFound = FALSE;

    while (letterFound == FALSE && d < [userWordLetters count]) 
    {
        if ([originalLetter caseInsensitiveCompare:[userWordLetters objectAtIndex:d]] == NSOrderedSame) 
        {
            //NSLog(@"letter %i correct", d+1);
            letterFound = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog(@"letter %i false", d+1);
            failedLetters++;
        }
        d++;
    }
}
```

I have a working algorithm where you can compare two strings. And put out the mistakes

I've uploaded the sample project to GitHub:
[NSString compareTwoStrings: algorithm outputs the mistakes](https://github.com/SomethingIsGrazy/StringCompare)

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear/post some code you have tried?

Comment: if edited my post with a code. I have also writtn a code which works if the user missed a letter/space but if two same letters in the word it also doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is compute the [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](https://github.com/JanX2/NSString-DamerauLevenshtein) between two strings. Here is an open source implementation for `NSString`: [GitHub JanX2/NSString-DamerauLevenshtein](https://github.com/JanX2/NSString-DamerauLevenshtein)

Comment: No, i haven't used this project. I once wrote my own implementation of the algorithm but i cannot found the code anymore.

Comment: Cool, ive done it to, I upload my NSString compair SampleProject

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSScanner` to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, i check it out.

Comment: are you sure that I can solve the problems with NSScanner, I dont tested any code but I read the apple documentation and I think that it isnt work for me.